# How to programmatically add photos to cmb2 meta field type file_list from front-end with multiple file inputs

Tags: php, wordpress

My code to create the CMB2 field

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => 'Qualification List',
    'desc' => 'Candidate qualifications',
    'id'   => 'qualification_file_list',
    'type' => 'file_list',
    'preview_size' => arraay( 100, 100 ), // Default: array( 50, 50 )
    'text' => array(
        'add_upload_files_text' => 'Upload Qualifications', // default: "Add or Upload Files"
        'remove_image_text' => 'Remove Image', // default: "Remove Image"
        'file_text' => 'File', // default: "File:"
        'file_download_text' => 'Download', // default: "Download"
        'remove_text' => 'Remove', // default: "Remove"
    ),
) );
```

HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="avatar">Upload your certificates:</label>
   <input type="file" id="qualifications" name="qualifications[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple><br>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'qualifications', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
    <span class="qualification-error-message"></span>
</div>
```

My code to upload images to the media library and attach images to the CMB2 file list

```
if ( ! empty( $_FILES['qualifications'] )  ) {
$files = $_FILES['qualifications'];
$new_file_img = [];
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value){
    if ($files['name'][$key]){
        $file = array(
        'name' => $files['name'][$key],
        'type' => $files['type'][$key],
        'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
        'error' => $files['error'][$key],
        'size' => $files['size'][$key]
        );
    }
    $_FILES = array("qualifications" => $file);
    $i=1;

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
          if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

            $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $acceptanceId);
            $new_file_img = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id );
            
            $i++;
    }
    echo $new_file_img;
    update_post_meta($acceptanceId, 'qualification_file_list',  $new_file_img);
}
}
```

I was able to get the files to upload to the WordPress media library where it says the file was uploaded to the post but the file is not attached to the field type.

image uploading using the code above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is :

Array :

```
$files[$attach_id] = $movefile["url"];
```

and update like this :

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery', $files);
```

I found the solution here https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/issues/1321

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do here is basically collect all the uploaded images into an array with key as the attachment id and value as the image url, then update post_meta. It might also be appropriate to generate metadata for the image as soon as the uploading of image is done,as I assume wordpress donot automatically generate metadata for the image in this case.

So your code may look like:

```
$files = $_FILES['qualifications'];
$gallery_images = array();

if (!empty($files)) {
    $directory = wp_upload_dir();
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        $new_file_mime = mime_content_type($files['tmp_name'][$key]);
        if (!in_array($new_file_mime, get_allowed_mime_types())) {
            return; //invalid file format
        } else {
            $file_path = $directory['path'] . '/' . $files['name'][$key];
        }

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');

        if (move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$key], $file_path)) {
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment(
                array(
                    'guid'           => $file_path,
                    'post_mime_type' => $new_file_mime,
                    'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $files['name'][$key]),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                    'post_author'    => $user->ID,
                ),
                $file_path,
                0,
                true
            );

            $image_added = array(
                $attach_id => $directory['url'] . '/' . $files['name'][$key],
            );
            wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_path);
            $gallery_images += $image_added;
        }
    }
}

update_post_meta($acceptanceId, 'qualification_file_list', $gallery_images);
```